# Unsafe C# - passing an unsafe pointer to a method

Tags: c#, pointers, native, unsafe

I receive an unsafe `byte*` type pointer to a 2-dimensional dataset in one of the methods of my class. I want to define another method in the same class that will do some pointer arithmetic on this pointer. When I tried to define the method as follows, I got several compile time errors. Looks like the use of `unsafe` keyword is not allowed at class scope. How do I work around this?

```
unsafe
{
    private byte* ReadIntoMemory(int rowIndex, int colIndex, int rowSize, int colSize, byte *abc)
    {
    }
}
```

If I do not use `unsafe`, then the compiler flags `byte*` parameter of the method as invalid syntax.

I was trying to code the `ReadIntoMemory` method to return the reference to the correct memory location for code written as follows -

```
byte *interestingMemoryLocation = ReadIntoMemory(locX, locY, sizeX, sizeY, basePointer);
```

Comment: It looks like you can declare an unsafe method. See the [c# docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx).

Comment: were you looking for `private unsafe byte* ReadIntoMemory(…`

Comment: @stuartd thanks. That did it. Do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: @Flamespotter done, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the unsafe keyword into the method signature:

```
private unsafe byte* ReadIntoMemory(…
```